# setting DropDown values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the data fetched from WebAPI and stored in a state called items

```
this.setState({
    items: dataSource
  staffId: ''
})
```

This state of items will be this.

```
[
    {"departmentName":"KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE","employeeName":"AUNG THU1", "staffId" : "00001"},
    {"departmentName":"KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE","employeeName":"AUNG THU2", "staffId" : "00002"},
    {"departmentName":"KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE","employeeName":"AUNG THU3", "staffId" : "00003"}
]
```

I would like to create a dropdown in react native with just the emplyeeName

```
let staff = [{
      value: 'AUNG THU1',
    }, {
      value: 'AUNG THU2',
    }, {
      value: 'AUNG THU3',
    }];
```

```
<Dropdown
    label='Staff Name'
    baseColor='#0079b5'
    data={staff}
    onChangeText={(value) => this.onChangeName(value)}
/>
```

**Edit:** Thank you for the answers! I would like to know whether it is possible to get the staffId of the selected value in DropDown? So if i were to select **AUNG THU 1**, the onChange method would trigger and I would like to set the state of staffId to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your array, try below approach

```
let dataSource = [
  { departmentName: "KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE", employeeName: "AUNG THU1" },
  { departmentName: "KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE", employeeName: "AUNG THU2" },
  { departmentName: "KYAUKSE MAINTENANCE", employeeName: "AUNG THU3" }
];

let staff = dataSource.map(item => ({
  value: item.employeeName,
  staffId: item.staffId
}));

console.log(staff);
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer,but is there a way I can get the id of the chosen employee? For example, if I were to choose ```AUNG THU1``` in the dropdown, I would like to get the value of his ```staffId```.

Comment: @MinUD check your ```Dropdown``` there should be props to get the selected value.

Comment: It says selectedValue is "Value matching value of one of the items".
so i pass ```selectedValue={value}```, whereas my ```onChangeText={(staffId) => this.onChangeName(staffId)}```. Will I be able to get the staffId this way?

Comment: @MinUD what is the library which you used for ```Dropdown```?

Comment: It is ```react-native-material-dropdown```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Dropdown component. It may be expecting a data array that has both keys and values.

```
let staff = [{
  key: 'AUNG THU1',
  value: 'AUNG THU1'
}, {
  key: 'AUNG THU2',
  value: 'AUNG THU2'
}, {
  key: 'AUNG THU3',
  value: 'AUNG THU3'
}];
```